# Error message caught by Axios is undefined in production, but works locally?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I have a function that sends an `axios` rrequest to my springboot backend.

```
  async createUser(user) {
    return axios.post(API_BASE_URL + "users/register", user).catch((error) => {
      console.log("the error: " + error.response.data.message);
      throw error.response.data.message;
    });
  }
```

For some reason, when I run the project locally, I am able to get the error message above, but when I deploy the project to production, the error message is `undefined`.

**Example of the above print statement^:**

Error message when ran locally: `the error: Email must be a work email. The email zx is NOT allowed.`

Error message when deployed: `the error: undefined`

**Code from my backend:**
The controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/api/users/register")
    public User registerUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return userServices.createUser(user);
    }
```

```
    public User createUser(User userDetails) {
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(emailExists(userDetails.getEmail()))) {
            throw new DuplicateResourceException(
                    "There is already an account with that email address: " +
                            userDetails.getEmail());
        }
        if (!userDetails.getEmail().toLowerCase().endsWith("@company.com")) {
            throw new NotAllowedException(
                    "Email must be a work email. The email " +
                            userDetails.getEmail() + " is NOT allowed.");
        }
        if (!userDetails.getCompanyPasscode().equals(env.getProperty("company.passcode"))) {
            throw new NotAllowedException(
                    "Incorrect company passcode");
        }
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(userDetails.getEmail());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userDetails.getPassword()));
        return userRepo.save(user);
    }
```

So if you look that the above function, you can see that when I run the project locally, I can get the `NotAllowedException` to be thrown back to my frontend, but not when deplpyed.

I read online that it could be due to a CORS header issue, but I don't think so because this is my `CORS` configuration and it still isn't working:

```
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();

        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;

    }
```

This is an example of one of my custom Exception classes:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class NotAllowedException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public NotAllowedException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you look into your Browser -- Developer Toolbar -- Network Tab and actually see if you have any exceptions on the console that you are not seeing.

Also is the call actually hitting the backend in this case?

Comment: If I look in Developer Toolbar, I see my payload is correct and the response is `400`. Which does get returned to the frontend. If I create a user (with an email that will work) then the user is created successfully, so I know that my endpoint is working. Its just when it fails, the error is not returned. The response from Developer toolbar when deployed is `{"timestamp":"2022-03-14T14:37:50.489+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","path":"/api/users/register"}`

Comment: From what you said the problem is not axios but the endpoint. Are other endpoints working correctly? It may be a configuration error. Check your env variables

Comment: Yep all endpoints are working successfully. But if I intentionally make an endpoint return an error, then the error is not returned to frontend (but it is when ran locally). For example, I throw an error if a user tries to create an account using an email that has already been registered, and that error is not making it back to my frontend. The only error I get is a `Request failed with status code 400`

Comment: Did you check server logs as well, if you can spot any exception or message there? You can start the backlog with the commandline parameter `--debug` to increase logging inside Spring Boot (does _not_ set all loggers levels to debug)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you should enable this application properties in application configuration.

```
server:
  error:
  include-message: always
```

More details [here](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-exception-handling/).

Comment: That looks like what I need. I use an `application.properties` file though for configuration. How can I put that configuration in that file?

Comment: Figure it out with your help. Just had to add `server.error.include-message = always` to the `application.properties` file

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a more scientific approach where you design error models based on what will work best in UI displays and API logs.

**AXIOS IN THE CLIENT**

You can't rely on always receiving an error response body. Eg sometimes you may get an empty 502 bad gateway error.

Write code defensively, and in all cases translate to the UI's error model. A possible way of coding in [this example code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/errors/errorFactory.ts#L119).

**SPRING IN THE SERVER**

Again define an error payload, eg with a `code` and `message` or whatever your company thinks will work best. [Exception filters](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/interceptors/UnhandledExceptionHandler.java#L38) will enable you to control the response format.

In Spring there can be multiple such filters. You may be happy with Spring's default error format, but you are not limited to it. Spring is an extensible franework that you can customize as required.

Answer (score 0):

From doing some searching, I've found a few people saying they have this problem when the Java on the 2 systems are different versions.